# Query where a number is not in a column?

Tags: sql

I have an sql database with a table holding users(UserID, Name), a table holding events(EventID, EventName), a table holding roles(RoleID, RoleName) and a table assigning roles to users for each event (assignID, EventID, UserID, RoleID).

Now I wanna get a list of all the events that do not contain a certain role, say every event without the roleID 1, but I don't want any rows with a different roleID.
how would I do that?

Comment: Please clarify: "but I don't want any rows with a different roleID"

Comment: I can't see a problem here !!

Comment: I don't want all the rows with roleID 2 or roleID 3, I want to know which events do not contain a roleID 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE eventid NOT IN 
     (SELECT eventid FROM assign WHERE roleID=1)
```

Or if subqueries are not available

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM events e 
  LEFT JOIN assign a ON (e.eventid=a.eventid AND a.roleid=1) 
WHERE a.roleid IS NULL
```

One more equivalent query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM events e 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT * FROM assign a WHERE a.eventid=e.eventid AND roleID=1)
```

Comment: @ypercube: I would be interessted in how well a correlated subquery (3. query) performances against the other two

Comment: DBMS optimizers may identify these (3 and 1) as equivalent and produce identical plans. Possibly with query 2, no idea without testing.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I figured but thought you might have more insight on whether this is actually happen (no need to test though)

Comment: @stryba: See this article: [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Comment: And: [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: Oh, one more thing. You can remove the `DISTINCT` in query2, it's not needed.